# Play Framework 2.3 Scala - Serialize nested objects to JSon with implicit Writes converters

Tags: json, scala, playframework, jsonserializer, playframework-json

I need for a frontend jquery-component a specific json object like this (ajax response):

```
[
    {"division":"IT", "contacts":[
        {“firstname”:”Carl”, “surname”:”Smith”, “empID”:1},
        {“firstname”:”Henry”, “surname”:”Miller”, “empID”:2}
]}, 
    {"division":"Sales", "contacts":[
        {“firstname”:”Nancy”, “surname”:”McDonald”, “empID”:3},
        {“firstname”:”Susan”, “surname”:”McBright”, “empID”:4}
]}
]
```

In Backend the data is read via anorm (MySQL) and transformed in following object:

```
List(Map("division" -> "IT", "contacts" -> List(c3,c4)), Map("division" -> "Sales",          "contacts" -> List(c3,c4)))
```

Then I try to serialize the Object to JSon but without success (including implicit Writes converters). Below I made a simplified test case Idea-Worksheet in the same manner:

```
import play.api.libs.json.{JsValue, Json, Writes}

case class Contact(firstname: String, surname: String, empID: Option[Int])

case class ContactDivisionList(division: String, contacts: Seq[Contact])

implicit val ctWrites = new Writes[Contact] {
  def writes(ct: Contact) = Json.obj(
    "firstname" -> ct.firstname,
    "surname" -> ct.surname,
    "empid" -> ct.empID
  )
}

implicit val sdlWrites = new Writes[ContactDivisionList] {
  def writes(dlist: ContactDivisionList) = Json.obj(
    "division" -> dlist.division,
    "contacts" -> Json.toJson(dlist.contacts)
  )
}


/*
Example
*/
val c1 = Contact("Carl","Smith",Option(1))
val c2 = Contact("Henry","Miller",Option(2))
val c3 = Contact("Nancy","McDonald",Option(3))
val c4 = Contact("Susan","McBright",Option(4))

//Test case 1 ->OK
Json.toJson(List(c1,c2,c3,c4))

//Test case 2 ->OK
val c_comp1=List(Map("contacts" -> List(c1,c2)),Map("contacts" -> List(c3,c4)))
//RESULT --> c_comp1: List[scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,List[Contact]]] =     List(Map(contacts -> List(Contact(Carl,Smith,Some(1)), Contact(Henry,Miller,Some(2)))),   Map(contacts -> List(Contact(Nancy,McDonald,Some(3)), Contact(Susan,McBright,Some(4)))))
Json.toJson(c_comp1)
//res1: play.api.libs.json.JsValue = [{"contacts":    [{"firstname":"Carl","surname":"Smith","empid":1},{"firstname":"Henry","surname":"Miller","empid":2}]},{"contacts":[{"firstname":"Nancy","surname":"McDonald","empid":3},{"firstname":"Susan","surname":"McBright","empid":4}]}]


//Test case 3 ->Fail!!!
val c_comp2 = List(Map("division" -> "IT", "contacts" -> List(c1,c2)),Map("division" ->  "Sales", "contacts" -> List(c3,c4)))
//sdlWrites: play.api.libs.json.Writes[ContactDivisionList]{def writes(dlist:    ContactDivisionList): play.api.libs.json.JsObject} = $anon$2@3738baec

Json.toJson(c_comp2)
//!!!!!Error messages
/*Error:(39, 13) No Json serializer found for type     List[scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,java.io.Serializable]]. Try to implement an    implicit Writes or Format for this type.
Json.toJson(c_comp2)
^

Error:(39, 13) not enough arguments for method toJson: (implicit tjs:    play.api.libs.json.Writes[List[scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,java.io.Serializable]]    ])play.api.libs.json.JsValue.
Unspecified value parameter tjs.
Json.toJson(c_comp2)
^
*/
```

At the end of the script you can see "Test case 3" that got an error when i execute Json.toJson(c_comp2) -->"No Json serializer found for type..". I try a lot of things but i don't get it right. The only difference to successful "Test case 2" is that i extend the Map with a String-Tuppel.

I hope sombody can help me with that issue, Thx

Best regards
Karsten

Comment: Thanks jilen,  but is there a difference betwen your suggested case class ContactGroup and my case class in the Script "ContactDivisionList"?

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that the `Map` you have there is mapping `String` to the least upper bound of `String` (your division name) and `List[Contact]`, which happens to be `java.io.Serializable`.

```
scala> case class Contact(firstname: String, surname: String, empID: Option[Int])
defined class Contact

scala> case class ContactDivisionList(division: String, contacts: Seq[Contact])
defined class ContactDivisionList

scala> val c1 = Contact("Carl","Smith",Option(1))
c1: Contact = Contact(Carl,Smith,Some(1))

scala> val c2 = Contact("Henry","Miller",Option(2))
c2: Contact = Contact(Henry,Miller,Some(2))

scala> val c3 = Contact("Nancy","McDonald",Option(3))
c3: Contact = Contact(Nancy,McDonald,Some(3))

scala> val c4 = Contact("Susan","McBright",Option(4))
c4: Contact = Contact(Susan,McBright,Some(4))

scala> Map("division" -> "IT", "contacts" -> List(c1,c2))
res10: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,java.io.Serializable] = Map(division -> IT, contacts -> List(Contact(Carl,Smith,Some(1)), Contact(Henry,Miller,Some(2))))
```

I'm not entirely sure the nature of your problem, but if you already have `List[ContactDivisionList]`, it's pretty straightforward to serialize that to JSON:

```
scala> implicit val contactWrites = Json.writes[Contact]
contactWrites: play.api.libs.json.OWrites[Contact] = play.api.libs.json.OWrites$$anon$2@3676af92

scala> implicit val contactDivisionListWrites = Json.writes[ContactDivisionList]
contactDivisionListWrites: play.api.libs.json.OWrites[ContactDivisionList] = play.api.libs.json.OWrites$$anon$2@2999d17d

scala> Json.toJson(List(ContactDivisionList("IT", List(c1,c2)), ContactDivisionList("Sales", List(c3, c4))))
res2: play.api.libs.json.JsValue = [{"division":"IT","contacts":[{"firstname":"Carl","surname":"Smith","empID":1},{"firstname":"Henry","surname":"Miller","empID":2}]},{"division":"Sales","contacts":[{"firstname":"Nancy","surname":"McDonald","empID":3},{"firstname":"Susan","surname":"McBright","empID":4}]}]
```

It seems to me that you should avoid having that `Map` in the first place. I've never worked with anorm before, but I think where you need to be looking at is the code that data structure, because at that point, you've lost typesafety. You should ideally work with `ContactDivisionList` or construct your object using the `JsValue` cases directly.